# Ubuntu can't login after set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for CUDA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, cuda

I'm having a problem with my configuration of LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable for UBUNTU.

My system configuration is the following: UBUNTU 17.10 CUDA 8.0 (required by Tensorflow) NVIDIA DRIVER 387.26

My current LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set as follow in the .profile file: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/nvidia-387:/usr/local/cuda/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}"

I had to include also /usr/lib/nvidia-387 because of this

I also had to set my primary graphic controller to "INTEL" because I wanted my GPU free from any other graphic process (basically I run sudo prime-select intel)

However when /usr/lib/nvidia-387 is set I can't login to my profile anymore: after password input I just get a black screen for several seconds, and I eventually return to the login screen.

I also attach my current XORG conf (copied and pasted from other similar topic).

```
Section "ServerLayout"
  Identifier "layout"
  Screen 0 "nvidia"
  Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
  Identifier "intel"
  Driver "modesetting"
  BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
  Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier "intel"
   Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier "nvidia"
   Driver "nvidia"
   BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
   Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier "nvidia"
   Device "nvidia"
   Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
   Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Any idea how to solve? It's important that I keep the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as is.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't solve the problem. But I have a workaround for you.

**1. edit `/etc/default/grub`**

Modify `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='pcie_port_pm=off acpi_backlight=none acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"'
```

This step is to prevent blank screen after logging in.

**2. move nvidia library directories to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf`**

The content of `nvidia.conf` is

```
/usr/lib/nvidia-390
/usr/lib32/nvidia-390
```

These directories depends on driver version on your computer.

**3. create `/etc/init.d/nvidia`**

To disable and enable nvidia runtime libraries.

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          nvidia 
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     5
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Short-Description: load/unload nvidia library
# Description:       load/unload nvidia library
### END INIT INFO

PRIME=$(prime-select query)
if [ "$PRIME" = "nvidia" ]; then
    exit 0
fi

case "$1" in
  start)
    sleep 10
    cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d
    mv nvidia.conf.bak nvidia.conf
    ldconfig
    nvidia-smi
    ;;
  stop)
    cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d
    mv nvidia.conf nvidia.conf.bak
    ldconfig
esac
```

**4. execute `update-rc.d nvidia defaults`**

You should find `SXXnvidia` in `/etc/rc5.d/` and `KXXnvidia` in `/etc/rc6.d/`, `/etc/rc0.d/`.

Try to execute `/etc/init.d/nvidia stop` and `nvidia-smi`, you should see error messages of libraries not found.

Try to execute `/etc/init.d/nvidia start`, then `nvidia-smi` is fine again.

If everything is OK, you can reboot now. You are expected to login to desktop.

**5. If anything goes wrong**

The most possible problem is `nvidia` script not executed. If it happens, you can press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to tty mode, execute `/etc/init.d/nvidia stop; reboot`. Then you can go back to unity desktop to debug.

**6. known side-effect**

When use intel as prime GPU, `unity-control-center`(system settings) will be failed to start.

```
GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion `string != NULL' failed.
```

**Note: my system spec**

```
# uname -r
4.13.0-32-generic
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
# dpkg -l | grep cuda
ii  cuda-9-0                                    9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA 9.0 meta-package
ii  cuda-command-line-tools-9-0                 9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA command-line tools
ii  cuda-core-9-0                               9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA core tools
ii  cuda-cublas-9-0                             9.0.176.1-1                                  amd64        CUBLAS native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-cublas-dev-9-0                         9.0.176.1-1                                  amd64        CUBLAS native dev links, headers
ii  cuda-cudart-9-0                             9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA Runtime native Libraries
ii  cuda-cudart-dev-9-0                         9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA Runtime native dev links, headers
ii  cuda-cufft-9-0                              9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUFFT native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-cufft-dev-9-0                          9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUFFT native dev links, headers
ii  cuda-curand-9-0                             9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CURAND native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-curand-dev-9-0                         9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CURAND native dev links, headers
ii  cuda-cusolver-9-0                           9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA solver native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-cusolver-dev-9-0                       9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA solver native dev links, headers
ii  cuda-cusparse-9-0                           9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUSPARSE native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-cusparse-dev-9-0                       9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUSPARSE native dev links, headers
ii  cuda-demo-suite-9-0                         9.0.176-1                                    amd64        Demo suite for CUDA
ii  cuda-documentation-9-0                      9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA documentation
ii  cuda-driver-dev-9-0                         9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA Driver native dev stub library
ii  cuda-drivers                                390.12-1                                     amd64        CUDA Driver meta-package
ii  cuda-libraries-9-0                          9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA Libraries 9.0 meta-package
ii  cuda-libraries-dev-9-0                      9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA Libraries 9.0 development meta-package
ii  cuda-license-9-0                            9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA licenses
ii  cuda-misc-headers-9-0                       9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA miscellaneous headers
ii  cuda-npp-9-0                                9.0.176-1                                    amd64        NPP native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-npp-dev-9-0                            9.0.176-1                                    amd64        NPP native dev links, headers
ii  cuda-nvgraph-9-0                            9.0.176-1                                    amd64        NVGRAPH native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-0                        9.0.176-1                                    amd64        NVGRAPH native dev links, headers
ii  cuda-nvml-dev-9-0                           9.0.176-1                                    amd64        NVML native dev links, headers
ii  cuda-nvrtc-9-0                              9.0.176-1                                    amd64        NVRTC native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-0                          9.0.176-1                                    amd64        NVRTC native dev links, headers
ii  cuda-repo-ubuntu1604                        9.1.85-1                                     amd64        cuda repository configuration files
ii  cuda-runtime-9-0                            9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA Runtime 9.0 meta-package
ii  cuda-samples-9-0                            9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA example applications
ii  cuda-toolkit-9-0                            9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA Toolkit 9.0 meta-package
ii  cuda-visual-tools-9-0                       9.0.176-1                                    amd64        CUDA visual tools
ii  libcuda1-390                                390.12-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA CUDA runtime library
ii  libcudnn7                                   7.0.5.15-1+cuda9.0                           amd64        cuDNN runtime libraries
ii  libcudnn7-dev                               7.0.5.15-1+cuda9.0                           amd64        cuDNN development libraries and headers
# dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-390                                  390.12-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 390.12
ii  nvidia-390-dev                              390.12-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-modprobe                             390.12-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-390                       390.12-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.2                                        amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                             390.12-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Comment: How can I tell if my BIOS is blocking my GPU? I'm not running UEFI but I want to make sure there isn't a secure boot issue.

Comment: Execute `nvidia-smi`. If will display GPU infomatrion if GPU is installed correctly.