# Installing NVidia Drivers consistently causes log in loop

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, dell

I've fairly new to Linux/Ubuntu, I currently have it installed on second partition alongside Windows 10.  I was happily using 16.04 on my laptop for a couple of weeks (using NVidia drivers), then I had some issues when I attempt to use a secondary monitor.  I thought maybe I could run the Xorg drivers over the NVidia ones, uninstalled the NVidia drivers and thought I had installed the Xorg ones.  Apparently that's not what happened, and I could not longer boot Ubuntu.

I tried to correct the problem with a liveCD in the for of a USB drive.  I reinstalled the NVidia driver and was met by an infinite log in, after a repeated attempts to solve the problem I was unable to.  So I decided to reinstall Ubuntu, I wiped the Ubuntu partitions and reinstalled it in the same place.  Ubuntu runs incredibly slowly, the UI takes moments to react and builds down from the top of the screen, I remembered this happening immediately after my original install but that it went away when I installed the NVidia drivers.  Every time I install the NVidia drivers (through:

`sudo apt install nvidia-390`

or whichever version I try) I end up with a log in loop, I can still get to the terminal with ctrl + alt + f1, so I can purge the drivers etc, but then I'm back to square one.  I've tried reinstalling a number of times, also tried 17.10 and Kubuntu, but can't get any of them to play ball.  I can't work out what's different between last week, when Ubuntu was running perfectly happily, and this one.

I'd like to reiterate that this happens every time I install NVidia drivers.

I am running a Dell XPS 15:

- 32GB of RAM
- 1TB SSD
- NVidia GeForce GTX1050 (4GB)
- Onboard Intel Graphics card
- Intel Core i7

Answer (score 1):

1. When you was failed to log in, use Ctrl+Alt+1 to the terminal. Type `sudo prime-select nvidia` to use nvidia as prime driver, and then reboot.
2. When you was failed to log in, use Ctrl+Alt+1 to the terminal. Find and remove nvidia libraries in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`. (For example, rename `nvidia.conf` to `nvidia.conf.bak`) Then reboot.

If either solution is working, you can refer to my answer to another similary problem: [Ubuntu can't login after set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for CUDA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994051/ubuntu-cant-login-after-set-ld-library-path-for-cuda/1003628#1003628)